# Units for silhouette measure

Tags: clustering, model-evaluation

While drawing graphs that compare the silhouette measure of different clustering algorithms, what unit should I specify for the silhouette width?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the Silhouette measure for arbitrary clustering algorithms. In particular, don't use it for clustering algorithms which can produce non-convex clusters.

On data sets such as this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SLINK-density-data.svg

the silhouette may be misleading.

The silhouette coefficient and silhouette plots are meant to compare different results of the same, convex, clustering algorithm (e.g. k-means).